# Excel: Dividend distribution with a cash reserve to avoid negative cash balances

Tags: excel, modeling, finance

I am trying to model a dividend distribution model with the following set-up:

```
Cash (beginning of period)
+ Cash Flow
- Distributions
=Cash (end of period)
```

over n-periods.

I would like Excel to ensure that the cash balance over all n-periods remains positive but all excess cash that could be distributed is actually distributed.
When I attempt this issue, I always end up with circular references.

Does anyone have an idea?

E.g. If in `period 1` I get `100` and `period 2` another `100` and in `period 3` the cash flow is `-50`, then I would like excel to distribute `100` in the 1st period, `50` in the 2nd and use the additional `50` cash from period 2 to cover the shortfall in period 3.

Thanks a bunch for your help!

Comment: Basically, I think you are having circular references because you are trying to use the data as its own source.  I think you should re-think the logic of the layout.  Have a sheet with facts about what happened (cash coming in and out recorded by date).  Then have a report sheet, or projections sheet that analyses that data however you want.  You can have multiple projections, and it won't affect the core data, because it's on a table on a separate sheet, just being referenced.  Unless I'm misunderstanding your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

In problems such as this it's sometimes helpful to work backward.  Let's assume you want the end balance to be exactly zero every period.  It's easy to calculate how much is available to be withdrawn at the end of the last period by looking at the last entry and using the end balance.  But you want to withdraw that balance as early as possible, so you want to move that value up to the previous period.

So, now look at the second to last entry.  This gets tricky, but you want to move the last available withdrawal up if you can, unless the available withdrawal exceeds the end of period balance.  Therefore, you use the min function, as shown below in column 3.

The next column is the desired end balance and it is the period end balance minus the available withdrawal.  It so happens that the desired end balance will accumulate from the bottom up any upcoming negative cash flows.  There may be another way to calculate this that is conceptually clearer, but this method seems to work.

Finally, once you know the desired end balance, a withdrawal amount can be calculated by taking the period end balance and subtracting the desired end balance.

The last column is the updated period end balance.

**The bottom line, is to work such problems backwards.**

Sorry, I can only post a CSV for the formulas.

```
Period,Cash,Cash flow,Backward Balances,Desired End Balance,Withdrawal,Cash at end
1,100,100,"=MIN(D3,B2+C2)",=B2+C2-D2,=B2+C2-E2,=B2+C2-F2
2,=B2+C2,100,"=MIN(D4,B3+C3)",=B3+C3-D3,=G2+C3-E3,=G2+C3-F3
3,=B3+C3,-50,"=MIN(D5,B4+C4)",=B4+C4-D4,=G3+C4-E4,=G3+C4-F4
4,=B4+C4,-19,"=MIN(D6,B5+C5)",=B5+C5-D5,=G4+C5-E5,=G4+C5-F5
5,=B5+C5,13,"=MIN(D7,B6+C6)",=B6+C6-D6,=G5+C6-E6,=G5+C6-F6
6,=B6+C6,-5,"=MIN(D8,B7+C7)",=B7+C7-D7,=G6+C7-E7,=G6+C7-F7
7,=B7+C7,,,,,
```

Please mark my answer if it helps.